# Text To Fade In On Button Click

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-5

How do I make it so that the text fades in when I have clicked the button. My code is currently set up so that some text is set to display:block while the rest are hidden with display:none.

Here is my JS code:

```
<script>

    //Select button by id
    const btn1 = document.getElementById('PowerApps');
    //Add on click listener for button
    btn1.addEventListener('click', function() {
        //Select (h1) heading by id, and then change it's value
        document.getElementById('PowerAppsText').style.display = 'block'
        document.getElementById('streamOpsText').style.display = 'none'
        document.getElementById('TogetherText').style.display = 'none'
    })

    //Select button by id
    const btn2 = document.getElementById('streamOps');
    //Add on click listener for button
    btn2.addEventListener('click', function() {
        //Select (h1) heading by id, and then change it's value
        document.getElementById('streamOpsText').style.display = 'block'
        document.getElementById('PowerAppsText').style.display = 'none'
        document.getElementById('TogetherText').style.display = 'none'
    })

    //Select button by id
    const btn3 = document.getElementById('Together');
    //Add on click listener for button
    btn3.addEventListener('click', function() {
        //Select (h1) heading by id, and then change it's value
        document.getElementById('TogetherText').style.display = 'block'
        document.getElementById('PowerAppsText').style.display = 'none'
        document.getElementById('streamOpsText').style.display = 'none'
    })


</script>
```

Here is my CSS code:

`#streamOpsText {
display: none;
}

#TogetherText {
display: none;
}`

Comment: You need to make an animation/transition on the `opacity`-property (from 1 to 0 for fading out, 0 to 1 for fading in). You can't animate the `display`-property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Important note;

`display:none;` and `display: block;` set whether or not the element 'exists', and should be read out or not.

Setting an element to `display:none;` doesn't just make it *invisible*, it functionally removes it (and all the place it takes up) from the DOM.

I'd suggest going for [visibility](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_visibility.php) instead of `display`, and/or fading in by transitioning the `opacity`.

---

**Keep in mind**; with visibility set to hidden (or opacity to 0), the element is not *visible* but it will still take up its full width and height.

Set these to **0** and size them along with the opacity transition.